How can I regain access to the root user in Ubuntu on WSL after creating a non-root user?
I installed Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) and created a user named siyam using adduser siyam and switched to this user with su - siyam. Now, I need to return to the root user to install software, but it asks for an administrator password. I tried using my Windows login password, but it didn't work. Since I wasn't prompted for a password when I created the siyam user or during the WSL installation, how can I regain access to the root user?

If you added your user to the group sudo, simply type sudo -i. It shall be the password of your current user siyam
